# Why is modulus % not working?

Tags: python, modulus

I am creating a program that uses age to determine factors such as annual fees, and to count annual fees i am using the modulus operator (%). For some reason a whole number % 1 is not creating 0.
Why is it doing this and how can I fix it?
My expected output is the word "year" printing every 12 iterations.

```
age=int(input("Age"))
quit=""
while quit!="quit":
    print(age%1)
    if age%1==0 or age%1==1:
        print("Year.")
    quit=input("Type quit to quit")
    age+=1/12
```

Comment: Look at the block below the if statement, it needs to be indented.

Comment: Can you rectify Indentation first ?

Comment: sorry, fixed indentation

Comment: anything mod 1 will be 0, what are you trying to check for?

Comment: checking if the number is whole, i am adding 1/12 each iteration

Comment: ANY number divided by 1 will give you a 0 mod result, not only the whole ones

Comment: have you run the code? for me it actually gives me decimals of twelfths

Comment: `1/12` is not the best way to iterate over months, because it equals `0.08333333333333333`. And what do you use age variable for?

Comment: I use it to calculate a car loan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you increment over `1/12` which is calculated to float and equals 0.08333333333333333. I'd suggest you to work with months instead of years

```
years = int(input("Age (years): "))
months = years * 12

# Don't use built-in quit
quit_message = ""
while quit_message != "quit":
    if months % 12 == 0:
        print("Year.")
    quit_message = input("Type quit to quit: ")
    months += 1

# I suppose you need an age in the end
print('{} year(s) {} month(s).'.format(*divmod(months, 12)))
```